# which(is.na(xtsSeries)) returns out of bounds values

Tags: r, xts, na

I have some time series in a xts object, with dimensions 54 * 5. I am interested in knowing which rows contain NAs. A call to `which(is.na(.))` gives me values that are greater than 54 (namely: 85, 108, ..). I don't understand what these values are?

```
> typeof(dataXtsW)
[1] "double"
> class(dataXtsW)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> dim(dataXtsW)
[1] 54  5
> which(is.na(dataXtsW))
[1]  54  85 108 162 216
> dataXtsW[85]
Error in `[.xts`(dataXtsW, 85) : subscript out of bounds
> dataXtsW[85,]
Error in `[.xts`(dataXtsW, 85, ) : subscript out of bounds
> dataXtsW[54,]
           NWHLNYHL Index LUHYTOBS Index SUM INX Index PCUSEQTR Index VIX Index
2017-04-21             NA             NA            NA             NA 0.1305778
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your example, `which()` will treat the data as a vector of length 54*5. Data in a matrix is stored column by column, so element 54 is the last element of the first column, 108 is the last element of the second column etc.

if you use `which( , arr.ind = TRUE)` you will get the array index (row,column) of the NA elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which rows contain `NA` you can find out using e.g.

```
which(apply(dataXtsW, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) any(is.na(x))))
```

where you check each row (`MARGIN = 1`) for `NA` values (`any(is.na(x)))`). If you use `which(is.na(dataXtsW))`, it returns the indixes of the `NA` elements of your data frame (not the rows!). The indices refer to the elements, ordered column-wise. In your case, the 54th element is `NA`. You can check this using

```
 unlist(dataXtsW)[54]
```